# webpage unable to load css file

Tags: css, external, href

this is a newbie question for you guys.

In file 
/home/myhome/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/view/test.jsp

I have `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/resources/view.css"/>`

and the view.css file is located at
/home/myhome/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/view/WEB-INF/resources/view.css

For some reason, it's not loading the css file.  But when I put the css file in the same directory as the jsp page and change href accordingly, it worked.  What did I do wrong in my attempt to load the file from another folder?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try**

Firebug, to debug if path is correctly loaded or not. As i can see it issue with path so you have to debug.

- http://www.ehow.com/how_2221659_debug-css-firebug.html

But you can try with this line instead

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/view/WEB-INF/resources/view.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using tomcat, I guess tomcat just won't let a page access anything in the WEB-INF folder, I moved the file else where not in WEB-INF, it worked...